# Failed to create and connect multiple tables using FOREIGN KEYS id in sqlite3 (C++)

Tags: sqlite

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    // Create and Open the bank.db databases
    int exit = sqlite3_open("bank.db", &DB);
    if (exit)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error open DB " <<  sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << std::endl;
        return(-1);   
    }

    std::string sql;
    char* messageError;
    
    // THIS WILL SUCCESSFULLY CREATE THE TABLE
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer("
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        "name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
        "dob       TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "gender    TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "address   VARCHAR(50),"
        "handphone TEXT NOT NULL);";

    exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError);
    if (exit != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error create table customer!" << std::endl;
        sqlite3_free(messageError);
    }

    // THIS WILL ALWAYS FAILED
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank_account("
        "customer_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(id),"
        "account_number     INT  NOT NULL,"
        "balance            INT  NOT NULL,"
        "username           TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "password           TEXT NOT NULL);";

    exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError);
    if (exit != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error create table bank_account!" << std::endl;
        sqlite3_free(messageError);
    }

    sqlite3_close(DB);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I tried to practice on using sqlite3 in C++. And as you can see in the code above, I tried to Create **Two tables** that connect each other using `id`.

First table, contain user information.

Second table, contain Bank Account information which will belong to user (first table) and connecting it using `id` `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(id)`.

When I run it, it successfully create the first table. BUT it always failed to create the second table `bank_account`.

The messageError says: **near "FOREIGN": syntax error.**

Can someone please tell me what is wrong? I see everyone wrote the syntax in that way. Thank You.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @user253751 The error message is what I wrote in the condition above: `std::cerr << "Error create table bank_account!" << std::endl; `. AND infact, it is not created in database `bank.dsb`

Comment: But what is the error message that comes from the sqlite3 library? It should tell you what the mistake is.

Comment: The last parameter of `sqlite3_exec` is a pointer to a place where SQLite will write its error message. Print that, please.

Comment: @Botje can you explain it?

Comment: `std::cout << messageError << std::endl`.

Comment: Oh, it says `near "FOREIGN": syntax error`

Comment: Remove `FOREIGN KEY` before REFERENCES.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up table and column constraints. Use one of the following:

Table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank_account
(
    customer_id     INTEGER,
    account_number  INT NOT NULL,
    balance         INT NOT NULL,
    username        TEXT NOT NULL,
    password        TEXT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
);
```

or a column constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank_account
(
    customer_id    INTEGER REFERENCES customer(id),
    account_number INT  NOT NULL,
    balance        INT  NOT NULL,
    username       TEXT NOT NULL,
    password       TEXT NOT NULL
);
```